# What does this proposition state regarding normal subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

If $K\triangleleft G$ so the subgroups from $G/K$ are quotient groups $H/K$ with $K<H<G$ and $H/K \triangleleft G/K$ is equivalent to $H \triangleleft G$.

I didn't understand "are quotient groups $H/K$". Does it mean that the subgroups from $G/K$ are given by $H/K$? Has this proposition been badly written?

Comment: These are two parts of the third isomorphism theorem (aka correspondence theorem). There is a one-to-one correspondence between the subgroups of $G$ containing $K$ and the subgroups of $G/K$, given by $H \mapsto H/K$. In this correspondence, $H$ is normal in $G$ iff $H/K$ is normal in $G/K$.

Comment: "Has this preposition been badly written?" is badly written (you probably mean proposition)! But yes, the subgroups of $G/K$ are all of the form $H/K$.

Comment: @DerekHolt so for $S_i \in G/K$ then $S_i=\{h_iK, h_i \in H\}$?

Comment: Yes that looks right!

Comment: why would you not put your answer out, it doesnt matter if that's very straightforward